# What is the worst case for binary search

Tags: search, runtime, time-complexity, binary-search

Where should an element be located in the array so that the run time of the Binary search algorithm is O(log n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first or last element will give the worst case complexity in binary search as you'll have to do maximum no of comparisons.
Example:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Here searching for 1 will give you the worst case, with the result coming in 4th pass.

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

In this case, searching for 8 will give the worst case, with the result coming in 4 passes.

Note that in the second case searching for 1 (the first element) can be done in just 3 passes. (compare 1 & 4, compare 1 & 2 and finally 1)

So, if no. of elements are even, the last element gives the worst case.

This is assuming all arrays are 0 indexed. This happens due to considering the mid as float of (start + end) /2.

Answer (score 1):

// Java implementation of iterative Binary Search

```
class BinarySearch
{
    // Returns index of x if it is present in arr[], 
    // else return -1
    int binarySearch(int arr[], int x)
    {
        int l = 0, r = arr.length - 1;
        while (l <= r)
        {
            int m = l + (r-l)/2;

            // Check if x is present at mid
            if (arr[m] == x)
                return m;

            // If x greater, ignore left half
            if (arr[m] < x)
                l = m + 1;

            // If x is smaller, ignore right half
            else
                r = m - 1;
        }

        // if we reach here, then element was 
        // not present
        return -1;
    }

    // Driver method to test above
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BinarySearch ob = new BinarySearch();
        int arr[] = {2, 3, 4, 10, 40};
        int n = arr.length;
        int x = 10;
        int result = ob.binarySearch(arr, x);
        if (result == -1)
            System.out.println("Element not present");
        else
            System.out.println("Element found at " + 
                                   "index " + result);
    }
}
```

Time Complexity:
The time complexity of Binary Search can be written as

T(n) = T(n/2) + c 
The above recurrence can be solved either using Recurrence T ree method or Master method. It falls in case II of Master Method and solution of the recurrence is Theta(Logn).

Auxiliary Space: O(1) in case of iterative implementation. In case of recursive implementation, O(Logn) recursion call stack space.